# Can we able to create a new Xamarin forms project using command line tool?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, command-line-interface

I want to create a Xamarin Forms App using command line tool. I am new to Xamarin and need guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the command line you could use [MvxScaffolding](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/MvxScaffolding) as it has a dotnet CLI version

Installation guide is [here](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/MvxScaffolding#dotnet-cli)

> dotnet new --install MvxScaffolding.Templates

Then use the Xamarin.forms mvvmcross template, detailed [here](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/MvxScaffolding/blob/develop/docs/template_dotnet_cli.md#mvxforms---xamarin-forms-template)

> dotnet new mvxforms --help

Here are some other [dotnet templates](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new) also [here](https://dotnetnew.azurewebsites.net/Search/xamarin)

The prism one is forms too

> dotnet new -i "Prism.Forms.QuickstartTemplates::*"